# Django - joining via the most recent through table row on a many-to-many

Tags: django

If I have a many-to-many relationship, with a custom through table, how can I join via only the most recent through table row? For example:

```py
class Price(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=21, decimal_places=2)


class PricingSchedules(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pricing_schedulesfd = models.ManyToManyField(
        PricingSchedules,
        related_name='pricing_schedule_set',
        through='ProductPricingSchedule',
    )


class ProductPricingSchedule(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pricing_schedule = models.ForeignKey(
        PricingSchedule,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product', 'pricing_schedule')
```

I realize these models are a little contrived, but the question still stands.

Say I want to select all products whose price is equal to "5.00", but I only want to consider the most recent row in the `ProductPricingSchedule` table, if any exists at all?

It should be noted that I don't actually care about the price as much as I care about being able to join through the most recent row for a Case/When annotation, something like this:

```py
Product.objects.annotate(
     is_match=Case(
         When(
         productpricingschedule__pricing_schedule__product__price__price=5.00,
         then=Value(True),
        ),
    default=Value(False),
    output_field=BooleanField(),
)).filter(is_match=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `related_name=` to `product` field in `ProductPricingSchedule` model

```
class ProductPricingSchedule(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_pricing_schedule")
    ...
```

and try

```
Product.objects.filter(pricing_schedulesfd__price__amount="5.00").order_by('-product_pricing_schedule__created_at')
```

Comment: This will not work, since it will not select projects who's most recent related row is 5. If there is an older related row that is 5, it will just select that one instead, and then just sort the entire query set by the related row regardless